Law of iterated expectations. Condition on past history.
Suppose I have a stochastic process ($X_t,Y_t$) and denote the filtration at t by $H_t=\sigma((X_l,Y_l)_{l=1…t})$. Further assume that $E(Y_t|H_{t-1},X_t)=0$. I am interested in computing
$$E(Y_t|X_t)$$
Is it correct to say
$$E(Y_t|X_t)=E(E(Y_t|X_t, H_{t-1})|X_t)=0$$
I am using Law of iterated expectation to condition on the past, and not familiar enough with measure theory to know if there’s a subtlety I am missing by doing so.

Looks correct to me. I will assume you know what $\sigma$-algebras are since you used them in your post. Then the LIE says that on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, for any sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{G}{1}\subset\mathcal{G}{2}\subset \mathcal{F}$, it holds that for an integrable random variable $Y$ that $E[Y|\mathcal{G}{1}] = E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}{2}]|\mathcal{G}{1}]$. Notice that this implies the result you want if you pick $\mathcal{G}{1} = \sigma(X_{t})$ and  $\mathcal{G}{2} = \sigma(X{t}, H_{t-1})$.

Intuitively, if you would just interpret $(\mathcal{G}{t}){t\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a growing information set or information accumulation over time, then it intuitively says that you cannot look into the future if you are at time $t$ when taking expectations. Perhaps this explanation does a better job of conveying the intuition.
